# What is my password for R-studio in dashDB console?

Tags: ibm-cloud, rstudio, dashdb

I have launched the dashDB console and wanted to use R studio. After launching R studio from the console page, I'm prompted for the username and password. Where do I retrieve my credentials for R-studio from Bluemix or dashDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Click on your dashDB service instance

**2)** You can launch dashDB service using "Launch" button top right hand side.

**3)** Once the dashDB dashboard loads, on left hand side, click on : Setup -> Connect Applications

**4)** You will find SSL/non-SSL connection information

Comment: Discovered that SSO to R-Studio is not available in dashDB. The credentials for R-studio is also available from the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable.